# What is the difference between symbian belle and Symbian Anna?

Tags: mobile, symbian, nokia-n8

What is the difference between symbian belle and Symbian Anna? Is it just small updation of Symbian ^3 or entirely a new os?

Answer (score 2):

Belle offers six home screens and the previous siblings of Symbian have 3 home screens only.

Widgets have been redesigned and are now available in five different sizes. Widgets can be rearranged to create complete personalized home screen.

Belle has taken a neat approach to notifications through – a pull down notification tab that incorporates common setting, notification for incoming messages, missed calls, etc.

Belle has introduced a toggle widget for one touch operation of Bluetooth, profile, Wi-Fi, etc.

Lock screen is active in Symbian Belle. It will tell about missed calls, incoming message, etc. Colored wallpaper can also be added to lock screen.

Near Field Communication (NFC) is integrated in the Symbian Belle operating system.

Belle incorporates new apps such as Microsoft Lync – an IM for business, SharePoint, OneNote, Exchange ActiveSync, and PowerPoint Broadcaster.

Answer (score 1):

**Symbian Anna** is the name for Symbian^3 PR2 (and PR means product release).

**Symbian Belle** is the name of the next update, and is a considerably larger update than Anna, with lots of UI changes.

Both use the same Symbian operating system, although Belle will have more updates. Most applications should be able to run on Symbian^3, Symbian Anna and Symbian Belle phones.

Symbian Anna can be updated on existing Symbian^3 phones such as the Nokia N8.

Symbian Belle can also be updated on Symbian^3 and Symbian Anna phones.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia has made a specific point of making both of the updates fully compatible with older handsets on the same basic platform, so Symbian^3 handsets such as the Nokia N8 and Nokia E7 have been issued with a Symbian Anna update, and will also benefit from an update to Symbian Belle too.

That will leave a single group of high-end Symbian handsets all running on the latest Symbian Belle platform within the next few months.

So what about the updates themselves? A common question we're seeing right now is which is the bigger update – Symbian Anna or Symbian Belle? Well, we say this having not had a chance to actually try out Symbian Belle yet, but it seems obvious even at this stage that it's a far more bigger step forward than Symbian Anna is, which is great news indeed.

In terms of headline improvements, Symbian Anna offers an attractive new icon design and font, a better web browser plus updates to other Nokia services, a portrait-style QWERTY keyboard and split-screen text entry.

Symbian Belle offers a doubling of the number of homescreens you can work with, the introduction of more flexible homescreen widgets in several different sizes, a wide range of NFC capabilities (though that will of course rely on your phone itself being NFC-enabled, which of the current range only the Nokia C7 is), a new status bar which takes a neat drop-down approach to notifications, dynamic real-time multitasking previews and a lock screen that shows additional detail, such as incoming messages and missed calls.

We'll have plenty of time to delve into the specifics of each of these improvements in due course, but as a whole they certainly give us a lot to look forward to.

There's no sign yet of any device-specific features being rolled out with the Symbian Belle update, as we've seen for the Nokia C7 and Nokia N8 with Symbian Anna. Time will tell, but we're certainly not complaining about what we've seen so far.

What do you make of Symbian Belle in the light of what Symbian Anna has to offer? Do you think the new features being lined up make for a bigger step forward than we've seen in Symbian Anna? Let us know what you think in the Comments!

Comment: There are currently some BC breaks between Anna and Belle. Some people are working on it. Also, I don't think you can upgrade to Belle without having Anna first.